# Azure Billing REST API Reference

Tags: rest, azure, api, billing

I am using Azure Billing REST API [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/reference/mt218998) (`v = azure.100`) to calculate costs in Azure.

But I'm noticing a difference between the prices returned by the API Resource [RateCard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/reference/mt219005%28v%3dazure.100%29) and prices returned by the 'CVS' cost file exported by the [portal](https://portal.azure.com) for example:

> 'API Resource RateCard' returned the following values ​​for MeterId = fec1d8d1-cc81-4d54-a391-83e228df4928

```
{
     "EffectiveDate": "2019-01-01T00: 00: 00Z",
     "IncludedQuantity": 0.0,
     "MeterCategory": "Storage",
     "MeterId": "fec1d8d1-cc81-4d54-a391-83e228df4928",
     "MeterName": "P4 discs",
     "MeterRates": {
          "0": 33.88120488
     },
     "MeterRegion": "South of Brazil",
     "MeterStatus": "Active",
     "MeterSubCategory": "Managed SSD Premium Disks",
     "MeterTags": [],
     "Unit": "1 / M"
},
```

Values ​​returned in the "CSV" file exported by the portal:

> Meter ID; Meter Category; Meter Sub-Category; Meter Region; Meter Name; Consumed Quantity; ResourceRate
>   fec1d8d1-cc81-4d54-a391-83e228df4928; Storage; Premium SSD; Managed Disks; BR South; P4 Disks; 0.032256; 36.033169798343473

The question:

The API returned the price of **33.88120488** and in the CVS file the price is **36.033169798343473**. Why does this difference occur? How can I calculate correctly using the API, do I have to include some tax?

Tks.

Comment: Excuse me for my unknown. What's the `CVS` file? Where can I see it on Azure portal?

Comment: In Azure portal "All services" -> "Subscriptions" , select a subscription, then in Tab "Cost Management" -> "Cost analysis" click Export

Comment: What filters did you selected for exporting CSV file?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? I have some similar questions on the CSV Export and API - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65477024/what-business-logic-is-the-azure-cost-export-applying